# Recuperar base de dados no Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tinha um servidor com várias bases de dados, porém ocorreu um erro e o servidor teve que ser formatado e eu consegui recuperar os dados através do `backup` que é feito diariamente pela empresa.

Consegui recuperar a pasta `Mysql` inteira, no entanto não sei como recupero minhas bases de dados a partir dessa pasta.

Como consigo recuperar essas bases?

Comment: Fazes backup da BD?

Comment: Apenas da pasta Mysql

Comment: Já aconteceu comigo. Dentro de MySql tem uma pasta "Data". Eu a substitui e funcionou.

Comment: acabei de substitui-la e não funcionou rsrs. É necessário reiniciar o servidor?